# Why sudo cat gives a Permission denied but sudo vim works fine?

Tags: bash, shell, echo, cat

I am trying to automate the addition of a repository source in my arch's pacman.conf file but using the `echo` command in my shell script.  However, it fails like this:-

```
sudo echo "[archlinuxfr]" >> /etc/pacman.conf
sudo echo "Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/\$arch" >> /etc/pacman.conf
sudo echo " " >> /etc/pacman.conf

-bash: /etc/pacman.conf: Permission denied
```

If I make changes to /etc/pacman.conf manually using vim, by doing

```
sudo vim /etc/pacman.conf
```

and quiting vim with `:wq`, everything works fine and my pacman.conf has been manually updated without "Permission denied" complaints.

Why is this so? And how do I get `sudo echo` to work? (btw, I tried using `sudo cat` too but that failed with Permission denied as well)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The problem is that the redirection is being processed by your original shell, not by `sudo`.  Shells are not capable of reading minds and do not know that that particular `>>` is meant for the `sudo` and not for it.

You need to:

1. quote the redirection ( so it is passed on to `sudo)`
2. **and** use `sudo -s` (so that `sudo` uses a shell to process the quoted redirection.)

Comment: So doing it in two steps like this
(1) `sudo -s`
(2) echo "# test" >> /etc/pacman.conf
works.

But is it possible to execute this in one single line?

Comment: `sudo -s 'echo "# test" >>/etc/pacman.conf'` is what I was trying to convey to you.

Comment: Actually, I tried that after reading your answer above but got a weird error like this:- `sudo -s 'echo "# test" >> /etc/pacman.conf'
/bin/bash: echo "# test" >> /etc/pacman.conf: No such file or directory` which is why I subsequently tried the 2-step manual process.

Comment: Ah..... one last attempt in this manner worked - `echo 'echo "# test" >> /etc/pacman.conf' | sudo -s`

Comment: Interesting, does your `sudo` configuration disable `-s`?  (Although it should report an error saying so in that case, instead of trying to run without a shell.)

Comment: how/where do I find out about `sudo` configuration disabling `-s` ? visudo?

Comment: `man sudoers`; and `man sudo` for `sudo -s` itself. `-s` might be disabled because it's harder to reliably control/secure what the `root`-run command does if a shell is involved (for similar reasons on many systems `-s` forces the `root` shell environment instead of the users as would be default).

Comment: @geekosaur Can you please show how looks the full command? For newbies like me can't follow what you mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 155):

As @geekosaur explained, the shell does the redirection before running the command.  When you type this:

```
sudo foo >/some/file
```

Your current shell process makes a copy of itself that first tries to open `/some/file` for writing, then if that succeeds it makes that file descriptor its standard output, and only if that succeeds does it execute `sudo`. This is failing at the first step.

If you're allowed (sudoer configs often preclude running shells), you can do something like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'foo >/some/file'
```

But I find a good solution in general is to use `| sudo tee` instead of `>` and `| sudo tee -a` instead of `>>`. That's especially useful if the redirection is the only reason I need `sudo` in the first place; after all, needlessly running processes as root is precisely what `sudo` was created to avoid. And running `echo` as root is just silly.

```
echo '[archlinuxfr]' | sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
echo 'Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch' | sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
echo ' ' | sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
```

I added `> /dev/null` on the end because `tee` sends its output to *both* the named file *and* its own standard output, and I don't need to see it on my terminal. (The `tee` command acts like a "T" connector in a physical pipeline, which is where it gets its name.)  And I switched to single quotes (`'`...`'`) instead of doubles (`"`...`"`) so that everything is literal and I didn't have to put a backslash in front of the `$` in `$arch`. (Without the quotes or backslash, `$arch` would get replaced by the value of the shell parameter `arch`, which probably doesn't exist, in which case the `$arch` is replaced by nothing and just vanishes.)

So that takes care of writing to files as root using `sudo`. Now for a lengthy digression on ways to output newline-containing text in a shell script. :)

To BLUF it, as they say, my preferred solution would be to just feed a here-document into the above `sudo tee` command; then there is no need for `cat` or `echo` or `printf` or any other commands at all. The single quotation marks have moved to the sentinel introduction `<<'EOF'`, but they have the same effect there: the body is treated as literal text, so `$arch` is left alone:

```
sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null <<'EOF'
[archlinuxfr]
Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch

EOF
```

But while that's how I'd do it, there are alternatives. Here are a few:

You can stick with one `echo` per line, but group all of them together in a subshell, so you only have to append to the file once:

```
(echo '[archlinuxfr]'
 echo 'Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch'
 echo ' ') | sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
```

If you add `-e` to the `echo` (and you're using a shell that supports that non-POSIX extension), you can embed newlines directly into the string using `\n`:

```
# NON-POSIX - NOT RECOMMENDED
echo -e '[archlinuxfr]\nServer = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch\n ' | 
  sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
```

But as it says above, that's not POSIX-specified behavior; your shell might just echo a literal `-e` followed by a string with a bunch of literal `\n`s instead. The POSIX way of doing that is to use `printf` instead of `echo`; it automatically treats its argument like `echo -e` does, but doesn't automatically append a newline at the end, so you have to stick an extra `\n` there, too:

```
printf '[archlinuxfr]\nServer = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch\n \n' | 
  sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
```

With either of those solutions, what the command gets as an argument string contains the two-character sequence `\n`, and it's up to the command program itself (the code inside `printf` or `echo`) to translate that into a newline. In many modern shells, you have the option of using ANSI quotes `$'`...`'`, which will translate sequences like `\n` into *literal* newlines before the command program ever sees the string. That means such strings work with any command whatsoever, including plain old `-e`-less `echo`:

```
echo $'[archlinuxfr]\nServer = http://repo.archlinux.fr/$arch\n ' | 
  sudo tee -a /etc/pacman.conf >/dev/null
```

But, while more portable than `echo -e`, ANSI quotes are still a non-POSIX extension.

And again, while those are all options, I prefer the straight `tee <<EOF` solution above.

Comment: Interesting! Could you add a note explaining the reason for also chunking the file to /dev/null?

Comment: `sudo bash -c 'foo >/some/file'` works for me on osx :-)

Comment: I prefer this answer because it works with multiline text.
`cat <<EOF | sudo tee -a /some/file > /dev/null ...`

Comment: That’s effectively my last answer, except you’ve added an extraneous `cat` process. :)

Answer (score 18):

http://www.innovationsts.com/blog/?p=2758

As the instructions are not that clear above I am using the instructions from that blog post. With examples so it is easier to see what you need to do.

> $ sudo cat /root/example.txt | gzip > /root/example.gz
>   -bash: /root/example.gz: Permission denied

Notice that it’s the second command (the gzip command) in the pipeline that causes the error. That’s where our technique of using bash with the -c option comes in.

> $ sudo bash -c 'cat /root/example.txt | gzip > /root/example.gz'
>   $ sudo ls /root/example.gz
>   /root/example.gz

We can see form the ls command’s output that the compressed file creation succeeded.

The second method is similar to the first in that we’re passing a command string to bash, but we’re doing it in a pipeline via sudo.

> $ sudo rm /root/example.gz
>   $ echo "cat /root/example.txt | gzip > /root/example.gz" | sudo bash
>   $ sudo ls /root/example.gz
>    /root/example.gz

Comment: For such a simple command, might be slightly better to use sh instead of bash.  E.g. sudo sh -c 'cat /root/example.txt | gzip > /root/example.gz'.  But otherwise, good explanations, +1.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "[archlinuxfr]" >> /etc/pacman.conf'
```

Answer (score 1):

**STEP 1** create a function in a bash file (`write_pacman.sh`)

```
#!/bin/bash

function write_pacman {
 tee -a /etc/pacman.conf > /dev/null << 'EOF'
  [archlinuxfr]
  Server = http://repo.archlinux.fr/\$arch
EOF
}
```

`'EOF'` will not interpret `$arch` variable.

**STE2** source bash file

```
$ source write_pacman.sh
```

**STEP 3** execute function

```
$ write_pacman
```

Comment: what is the quote on EOF for?

Answer (score 0):

append files (sudo cat):

```
cat <origin-file> | sudo tee -a <target-file>
```

append echo to file (sudo echo):

```
echo <origin> | sudo tee -a <target-file>
```

(EXTRA) disregard the ouput:

```
echo >origin> | sudo tee -a <target-file> >/dev/null
```