# Keep the show_compatibility_56 always ON in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I needed to set up the system variable "show_compatibility_56" to ON in MySQL. So, I run the command `set global show_compatibility_56 = on;`, and it worked However, I noticed that whenever I stop and then start the MySQL server, this variable goes back to OFF. Any hints on how to keep it **always ON** even if I restart the server?

Answer (score 23):

I'm using a Laravel Homestead (Vagrant) box (MySql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17).

I needed to SSH into Homestead and then run:

```
echo "[mysqld]
show_compatibility_56 = ON
performance_schema" | sudo tee -a /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf  >/dev/null    
sudo service mysql restart
```

(Thanks to [Mark Reed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10145083/470749) for showing how to skip opening vim.)

**Older** version:

`sudo vim /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysql.cnf`

Then I added this section:

```
[mysqld]
show_compatibility_56 = ON
performance_schema
```

**I was surprised that other answers here and elsewhere on the web didn't specify that it needed to be under `[mysqld]` instead of `[mysql]` and also that you must restart the MySql service:**

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

Comment: exactly, nobody gave a shit about [group] where to put that stupid configuration option

Comment: More help is `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES where Variable_name like '%show_compatibility%'` . It helps to test from SQL editor is it good yet or not

Comment: Ha, Google took me to my own answer 3 months later now that I'm facing this problem *again*. Win!

Comment: If you've installed mysql with homebrew and have homebrew services installed, restart mysql with `brew services restart mysql`.

Answer (score 3):

you need to save this variable setting in your configuration file my.cnf for linux and my.ini for windows.

Comment: Can you tell me please where can I find the my.ini file (I mean the path)?

Comment: As you are asking my.ini, so you can check at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" pathg just change version if you have different version and also there should be different program files (x86) as per your windows version.

Comment: I found this file 'my-default.ini' and I think this is the file that you are talking about. I added this line to it show_compatibility_56= on. However, it still not working properly and this property is set up to off once I stop and start the server.. Any hints?

Comment: make this file one more copy with name my.ini on same location and update your configuration in this file and then restart your mysql service.

Comment: Still it is not working although I have the my.ini file... Is adding the line show_compatibility_56= on is correct. Or I should write something else?

Comment: try with "show_compatibility_56 = 1", don't forgot to restart mysql service.

Comment: your mysql version...check by followig command if you are getting this variable "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'show_compatibility_56';" as this variable introduces from 5.7.6

Comment: Yes, I am getting the record, but I couldn't make the changes of this system variable 'show_compatibility_56' permanent. Whenever, I restart the server, it is assigned again OFF...

Comment: It is a bit long for a comment. Can I get ur email @, so I will email it to you?

Comment: This late reply just for future users, if someone is using a code from information_schema like "SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL variable_value SECOND) started_at FROM information_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Uptime';" then  no need to change this variable just change information_schema to performance_schema like "SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL variable_value SECOND) started_at FROM performance_schema.global_status WHERE variable_name='Uptime';"....Even if some one using such type queries in program/script (which should not be a case) and don't want to change in script then do it.

Answer (score 2):

To make it permanent, you need to add this variable in configuration file of MySQL like we did for all other variables as:

**show_compatibility_56 = ON**

**For Linux based system:**  File name is **my.cnf**  and default location is **/etc/my.cnf**

**For Windows based system:** File name is **my.ini**  and default location is your windows mysql data directory that you can check via below command:

> show variables like 'datadir';

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed MySQL through Hombrew on a Mac, there isn't a my.cnf by default.  I created one in `/etc/my.cnf`, added the text from @Ryan's answer:

```
[mysqld]
show_compatibility_56 = ON
performance_schema
```

... and then restarted MySQL, with (I'm using the older 5.7 version):

```
$ brew services restart mysql@5.7
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

As Zafar has already pointed you can set the variable in the configuration file to save the value.

Also note that this is now deprecated. The [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_show_compatibility_56) says:

> **Note**:
>
> show_compatibility_56 is deprecated because its only purpose is to
> permit control over deprecated system and status variable information
> sources that will be removed in a future MySQL release. When those
> sources are removed, show_compatibility_56 will have no purpose and
> will be removed as well.